# jquery toggle html changing

Tags: jquery, button, text

My question is when i click the 'A' button i want the 'vartalo' text change to 'hello' text and when i click the 'B' button i want 'pää' text to change to 'man' text, how can i do that ? is it possible with some more id's? sorry about my english

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nappulat').on('click', function(p) {

    p.preventDefault();

    var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');
    $('#' + panelid).toggle(1).html('hello')
  });
});
```

```css
#memberlist_links a {
  left: 800px;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: red;
  margin: 0px;
}
.paneelinpaa {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.paneelinvartalo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">

  <div class="backgroound">

    <div id="panel1" class="paneelinvartalo">vartalo
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="paneelinpaa">pää
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="memberlist_links">
    <br>
    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel1">A     
    </a> 
    <br><a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel2">B    
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding IDs onto your  tags and doing the following:

```
$('#buttonA').click(function () {
    $('#panel1').html('hello');
});

$('#buttonB').click(function () {
    $('#panel2').html('man');
});
```

Through the use of IDs you will make sure that you are always targeting the correct element in your DOM

Comment: i know this way but what if i have many of those for example if i had buttons 'abcdefg' ?? then there will be long code if i do this way, is there shorter way ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the new text in another `data` attribute.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nappulat').on('click', function(p) {

    p.preventDefault();

    var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');
    var message = $(this).data('message');
    $('#' + panelid).toggle(1).html(message);
  });
});
```

```css
#memberlist_links a {
  left: 800px;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: red;
  margin: 0px;
}
.paneelinpaa {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.paneelinvartalo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">

  <div class="backgroound">

    <div id="panel1" class="paneelinvartalo">vartalo
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="paneelinpaa">pää
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="memberlist_links">
    <br>
    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel1" data-message="hello">A     
    </a> 
    <br><a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel2" data-message="man">B    
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if i have many more buttons ? i just need to Put the new text in another data attribute ? isnt there shorter way ?

Comment: Do you mean the button needs to update more than one panel, with a different message in each one?

Comment: I would probably use an array or object in Javascript that contains all the mappings. Without seeing the whole structure that you're trying to implement it's hard to be more specific.